# First use of Bernoulli's inequality and its name

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, mathematicians

The Wikipedia article [“Bernoulli's inequality”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says, that this inequality is called after the mathematician [Jacob Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Bernoulli). Was he the first one using the inequality? Why is this inequality named after him? When was the inequality used first?

On the Talk page of the Wikipedia article is already [a thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Please_add_History) about this. Unfortunately the link provided there does not work anymore.

Comment: Fun Fact: Wikipedia now [cites Francois's answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Notes).

Comment: @HDE226868: I know, I added the section with the citation to the Wikipedia article... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Jacob Bernoulli** first published the inequality on the second page of his [*Positiones Arithmeticae de Seriebus Infinitis* (Basel, 1689)](https://archive.org/stream/jacobibernoulli00conggoog#page/n494), as follows:

> $$\textrm{IV.}$$
>   *Si sit Progressio Geometrica quaecunque A, B, C, D, E; & alia Arithmetica totidem terminorum A, B, F, G, H, incipiens ab iisdem terminis A & B, erunt reliquorum singuli in Geometrica singulis ordine sibi respondentibus in Arithmetica majores, tertius tertio, quartus quarto, ultimus ultimo, adeoque omnes omnibus.*

Bernoulli uses the inequality several times in the rest of his *Positiones* (a 100+-pages treatise in 5 parts). Quoth André Weil in [*Die Werke von Jakob Bernoulli. Band 4. Reihentheorie* (Basel, 1993)](https://zbmath.org//?q=an:921.01046), p.10:

> (Prop. IV) C'est le lemme $(1 + x)^n > 1+nx$, cité encore dans les ouvrages scolaires sous le nom de Bemoulli. Celui-ci en donne une démonstration basée sur le livre V d'Euclide; mais bien entendu ce lemme dit simplement que pour un taux d'intérêt donné il est plus coûteux d'emprunter à intérêts composés qu'à intérêt simple, et Bernoulli, qui à l'exemple de Leibniz avait dû se poser déjà des problèmes d'intérêts composés, avait probablement conscience de ce fait.

---

**Edit.** According to Joseph E. Hofmann, [*Über die Exercitatio Geometrica des M. A. Ricci* (1963)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=161779), p.177, the inequality is actually due to **Sluse** in his [*Mesolabum* (1668 edition)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ugJ1GtyH08kC&pg=PA114), Chapter IV "De maximis & minimis":

> Es lässt sich (in moderner Umschrift) in drei Zeilen hinschreiben:
>
> Ist $x>0$ (...), dann ist
>
> $$\frac{1+px}{1+(p-1)x}
> <\frac{1+(p-1)x}{1+(p-2)x}
> <\dots
> <\frac{1+2x}{1+x}
> <\frac{1+x}1\quad(\dots).\tag{4,11}$$
>
> Also ergibt sich durch “Zusammensetzen”, d.h. durch Multiplikation entsprechender Quotienten (...)
>
> $$1+px < (1+x)^p\quad(\dots).\tag{4,12}$$
>
> In Form der ersten Gleichung (4,12) steht die sog. Jak. **Bernoulli**sche Ungleichung erstmals im Druck vor uns. **Bernoulli** ist durchaus nicht der Erfinder dieser Ungleichung, hat sie jedoch vermutlich nicht direkt aus **Sluse**, sondern auf dem Umweg über I. **Barrow** (...) Auch in dessen [*Lectiones geometricae* (London, 1670)](https://archive.org/stream/mathematicalwor00whewgoog#page/n664) findet sich die Ungleichung, und zwar in der 7. Vorlesung, §13-16. Sie wird dort in einer Form bewiesen, die dem Vorgehen **Sluse**s sehr ähnlich ist (...)